# Maven: build Docker images of children projects

Tags: java, maven, docker, spring-boot

My project has the following structure:

```
pom.xml
  |
  x----child1
  |      |
  |      x----pom.xml
  |
  x----child2
         |
         x----pom.xml
```

There is a pom father and two children poms. The build of the children uses the Spotify Plugin to generate the Docker images of the projects. My question is, how can I invoke both the build from the root directory? I basically need to invoke the spotify plugin build on the children modules.
I tried to use

```
mvn clean install
```

but the children are built with maven-compiler-plugin, and not with the docker-maven-plugin.

This is the build I use in the children:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spotify.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>childImage</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../src/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the pom father I already defined the modules like this.

```
   <modules>
        <module>child1</module>
        <module>child2</module>
   </modules>
```

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of options to tackle this issue:

1. Configure the plugin in the parent pom's  section but default the plugin configuration to skip the docker build, and override that in the child module to not skip
2. Configure it only in the child module and bind the build goal to the package phase.

I have been using [2] with following in child pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
      <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.13</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>build</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <imageName>example</imageName>
        <baseImage>example</baseImage>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
            <directory>target</directory>
            <include>example.war</include>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the plugin:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>build</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```